# Mobile chat provides no feedback when a post is too long

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web

On desktop, chat gives you feedback when your message is too long: an alert appears and the send button becomes disabled.

On mobile however there is no warning and the button never disables. Your only way to determine your message is too long is to press send and notice nothing happened. If you don't know what this means, you're going to be confused about what's going on, like I was the first time I ran into this—I thought I was offline or something.

If you *do* know that means your message is too long, the next step of course would be to trim back your message until it's short enough to send, but the only way to know is by trial-and-error trying to send the message each time to check. On desktop, you get the feedback that the warning vanishes and the send button enables.

### Desktop screenshots

These were taken May 19th 2023 in Meta.SE's chat.

#### Short message

[image: desktop-short]

#### Long message

[image: desktop-long]

### Mobile screenshots

#### Short message

[image: mobile-short]

#### Long message

[image: mobile-long]

(No UI difference.)

Comment: You have thumbs of steel if you typed a post over the limit on a mobile device. Not that this makes the bug any less valid, I'm just amazed you ran in to it.

Comment: @jmac I used to have very long bus trips to get to work. I might have developed thumbs of steel during them.

Comment: Oh, chat! I thought you hit the question/answer length limitation and was really really worried (the answer limit is 30,000 characters -- typing that on a cell phone would be an incredible feat).

Comment: @jmac Oh boy. I'd probably wear curves into my screen before I hit that limit. :D (or cease to have thumbs)